# How to write grid in csv file in python

Tags: python, csv

I have a list of tuples. Each tuple contain 2 values, together with the results of an operation between the two values. Here is an example:

```
my_list = [(1,1,1.0), (1,2,0.8), (1,3,0.3), (2,1,0.8), (2,2,1.0), (2,3,0.5), (3,1,0.3), (3,2,0.5), (3,3,1.0)]
```

I need to store this value in a csv file so that they look like this:

```
0    1     2     3
1    1    0.8   0.3
2   0.8    1    0.5
3   0.3   0.5    1
```

In other words, I need to go to a new row every time the first number of the tuple change.

This is the function I am currently using, which writes each tuple in a new row (not what I want):

```
def write_csv(my_list, fname = ''):
    with open (fname, mode='a+') as f:
        f_writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        for x in my_list:
            f_writer.writerow([str(x[0]), str(x[1]), str(x[2])])
```

Any suggestion on how to modify (rewrite from scratch) it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a combination of the Numpy and Pandas Python libraries.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

my_list = [(1,1,1.0), (1,2,0.8), (1,3,0.3), (2,1,0.8), (2,2,1.0), (2,3,0.5), (3,1,0.3), (3,2,0.5), (3,3,1.0)]

new_list = [cell[2] for cell in my_list] # Extract cell values
np_array = np.array(new_list).reshape(3,3) # Create 3x3 matrix
df = pd.DataFrame(np_array) # Create a dataframe
df.to_csv("test.csv") # Write to a csv
```

For clarity, the dataframe will look like:

```
df
     0    1    2
0  1.0  0.8  0.3
1  0.8  1.0  0.5
2  0.3  0.5  1.0
```

And the csv file will look like:

```
,0,1,2
0,1.0,0.8,0.3
1,0.8,1.0,0.5
2,0.3,0.5,1.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will give it a try. Is there any way to make the matrix start from 1 instead of zero?

Comment: @ginopino you could do ```df.index += 1``` and ```df.columns += 1``` to increment the rows and columns by 1.